# What is Karma and paragon, and how to get it?

Tags: kittens-game

From the screenshots of a reddit post complaining about the bugs in 0.9.8.0 I saw that you can have karma and paragon. Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDHQE.png) to the picture. I didn't include it directly to avoid possible spoilers for other people. So don't click it if you don't want to know possible other resources.

How can I get this karma and paragon, what is it, and how does this effect my gameplay?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you reset a game you will get Karma and Paragon.

> **Karma**: Karma is gained when you reset with more than 35 kittens. Karma gives +10% happiness for having it, and 1% happiness for each
>   point as well. This does have a diminishing effect to keep it from
>   becoming too over powering. The exact numbers on the diminishing
>   effect are currently unknown.

- 40 kittens -> 1.00 Karma
- 50 kittens -> 2.00 Karma
- 62 kittens -> 3.16 karma
- 67 kittens -> 4.13 karma
- 73 kittens -> 5.07 karma
- 80 kittens -> 6.00 karma
- 89 kittens -> 7.02 karma
- 99 kittens -> 8.05 karma
- 110 kittens -> 9.00 karma
- 123 kittens -> 10.03 karma
- 137 kittens ->11.05 karma
- 152 kittens ->12.05 karma

> **Paragon**: Paragon is received for resetting at over 70 kittens.

Every paragon point will give

- 1% global production bonus
- 0.1% storage capacity

Why would you reset?

The reason a person would reset a game is to earn everything faster. Yes you have to start over again, but with all the extra happines, the production bonus and the extra storage capacity everything will go faster.

Also for getting some achievements it is neccesary to reset the game.

Reset or Wipe?

There is a difference between resetting and wiping. When you wipe the game you will destroy all your progress. You won't get any Paragon or Karma points when you do this.

If you reset you do get Paragon points and Karma and you won't lose all your game progress.

**NOTE: It'll take some time before you are back at where you are now if you reset the game, don't assume it'll go much more faster.**

**There is also an achievement**

`Lotus Eater Machine - Break the cycle of reincarnations -  Obtain karma by resetting game`

**Source**

[Achievement](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Achievements&redirect=no)

[Paragon](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=paragon&redirect=no)

[Karma](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=karma&redirect=no)

Comment: So it is advisable to restart the game multiple times, to get more karma/paragon and get to the endgame gaster, with more/better resource gathering? Ah, didn't see the edit yet. Thanks. Will reset then sometimes (with pain in my heart, probably).

Comment: I find it hard to say to be honest. Even with a reset you will have to start over again. It is just a bit faster. I don't think you should reset to often. I find it hard to start over multiple times if I reset to often. Also you need atleast 70kitten before resetting becomes usefull. A usefull tip from me, look at the achievements before resetting. Are you close to getting an achievement? It's maybe smart to first get that achievement.

Comment: How about killing first all my kittens (to get the 100 kills) and then restart? Because, there are not that much achievements.

Comment: And it is certainly something to do when you have at least some hours of free time, as it is quite time consuming to get everything just right after a restart, I think.

Comment: Yes kill your kittens, I assume you have the unicorn and unicorn tear achievement. And when you have more then 70 kittens you can reset your game. And yeah, restarting can be time consuming.

Comment: Not the tear yet. Probably because I never produced a megalith

Comment: What do you mean by "currently unknown"? Everything in the game has always been 100% known, because it's all client-side javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Damek's answer is great, but I should point out there is another way of getting Paragon. Every 1000 years (assuming you don't reset), you get 1 paragon as well.