# When to reset to maximise karma and paragon?

Tags: kittens-game

In [kittens game](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/), [karma](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Karma) and [paragon](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Paragon) are obtained via resetting with more than 35-70 kittens, and greatly improve production as global accelerators, becoming almost a necessity past some stage. [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185834/what-is-karma-and-paragon-and-how-to-get-it) yields more details on why to reset.

I read there was a diminishing returns effect happening after 200 paragons, but these nevertheless take a couple resets to obtain, and even paragon is necessary for [Metaphysics](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Metaphysics) upgrades.

**When should one reset in order to maximise paragon gathering ?** (say, per day of play)

I noticed after [`Mechanization`](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Technologies#Mechanization) and [`Concrete Huts`](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=workshop#Concrete_Huts) my kittens population seems to stagnate around 130 for a bit of time, so maybe that's a sweet spot, but what about  resetting just after `Ironwood Huts`, or is it worth waiting for `Unobtainium Huts`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Karma and paragon, and how to get it?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185834/what-is-karma-and-paragon-and-how-to-get-it)

Comment: Linked, but not a duplicate. The answer there states "The reason a person would reset a game is to earn everything faster." and my question is "when is it that 'faster' is 'fastest' ?"

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely down to your playstyle, and how quickly you can build your population.

The only sensible and universal answer I've heard when just trying to build paragon is "as soon as getting a few more kittens is slower than resetting and building population back up to earning paragon again."  Every answer is going to be dependent on how quickly you can climb the tech tree, how much you can push your storage caps, and then turn those things into more paragon kittens.

Comment: I'd guess "how fast can you build up back to where you were" to be fairly constant across players (maybe dependent on a certain paragon level) ; isn't it so ?

Comment: @Nikana - for players already with a large amount of paragon,  sure, but at the lower end population is heavily dependent on storage caps, which in turn is dependent on paragon.  Also depends on how much you wish to skip, not every tech is mandatory, but many are too helpful in the long run, so how short can you go, etc. My sweet spot is right around 170, but I rarely stop there, & yours might differ. Maybe a better player can answer better.